OAuth 2.0 Resource Server JWT, not valid Signature
after updating to Spring Boot 3.1.8 (especially Spring-Security 6.x) and Java 21 i get this error from my JWT.
My Www-Authenticate header by my client contains this error message:
Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT rejected: Invalid signature"

error in my backend is:
ERROR: 'invalid_token', DESCRIPTION 'true', URI 'https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1'

and my stacktrace is:
cause: 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.BadJwtException: An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: Signed JWT rejected: Invalid signature',
 stackTrace [org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.getJwt(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:103),
 org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(JwtAuthenticationProvider.java:88),
 org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:182),
 org.springframework.security.authentication.ObservationAuthenticationManager.lambda$authenticate$1(ObservationAuthenticationManager.java:54),
 io.micrometer.observation.Observation.lambda$observe$4(Observation.java:544),
 io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observeWithContext(Observation.java:603),
 io.micrometer.observation.Observation.observe(Observation.java:544),
 org.springframework.security.authentication.ObservationAuthenticationManager.authenticate(ObservationAuthenticationManager.java:53),

My applications.properties look like this:
auth:
  jwt:
    jwk-set-uri: http://some.service:9000
    claims:
      aud: "MY_CLOUD"
    publicKey:
    signingKey:
    selfSigned: false

before updating to Spring Boot 3.1.8 (SecurityFilterChain etc.) and Java 21, I used this lib to sign my jwt
implementation group: 'com.nimbusds', name: 'nimbus-jose-jwt', version: '9.24.4+'

and Java 11 with Spring Boot 2.7.18
And creation and signing of my  JWT token looks like this:
private String myToken() {
   
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    JWTClaimsSet claims = new JWTClaimsSet.Builder()
            .claim("sub_id", "xyz")
            .claim("groups", "myGroup")
            .issueTime(calendar.getTime())
            .expirationTime(DateUtils.addMinutes(calendar.getTime(),
                    30))
            .build();
    Payload payload = new Payload(claims.toJSONObject());
    JWSHeader header = new JWSHeader(JWSAlgorithm.RS256);
    JWSObject jwsObject = new JWSObject(header, payload);
    try {
        com.nimbusds.jose.JWSSigner jwsSigner = getJWSSigner();
        jwsObject.sign(jwsSigner);
    } catch (JOSEException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Fehler beim Signieren des JWTs aufgetreten", e);
    }
    return jwsObject.serialize();
}


private com.nimbusds.jose.JWSSigner getJWSSigner() throws KeyLengthException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    //variable 'signingKey will be injected from outside into container
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(signingKey.getBytes()));
    java.security.KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    java.security.PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
    return new RSASSASigner(privateKey);
}

and my JWTDecoder looks like this:
JwtDecoder publicKeyDecoder() {
    NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = null;      
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKey.getBytes()));
    RSAPublicKey rsaPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFactory.generatePublic(spec);
    jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(rsaPublicKey).build();
    jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(getTokenValidator());
    return jwtDecoder;
}

according this error my method getJWSSigner() is not working correctly with spring-boot 3.1.8
because so far i understand, my signature will be created in this method getJWSSigner(), which will be signed above jwsObject.sign(jwsSigner). But maybe this is wrong assumption.
After several attempts and updating nimbus-jose-jwt to version 9.37.3 i still get same error.
Also on jwt.io i get this message: Invalid Signature
First part header and second part payload will be decoded correctly, but third part is invalid.
If I am using same code and same key-value-pairs on Spring Boot 2.7.8, Java 11 and Nimbusds-Jose 9.24.4+ it works just fine.
Solution
Here is my securityFilterChain
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                    authorizeRequests.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,".*(/user)").permitAll())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer ->
                    oauth2ResourceServer
                            .jwt(jwt ->
                                    jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(new MyAuthenticatonConverter())
                                            .decoder(createJWTDecoderX()))
            )
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                    authorizeRequests.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,".*(/aticle)").permitAll())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer ->
                    oauth2ResourceServer
                            .jwt(jwt ->
                                    jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(new MyAuthenticatonConverter())
                                            .decoder(createJWTDecoderY())
            );
    return http.build();
}

The JWTAuthenticationprovier has one constructor.
Everytime, when a JWTDecoder will be defined, this constructor will be invoked. According this chain, i should have two different Autheticationproviders with two different JWTDecoders.
But after i've deleted one of them, the other one started to work.
This behavior from AutheticationProvider seems to be like a Singleton:
My solution-code
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                    authorizeRequests.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,".*(/user)").permitAll())
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2ResourceServer ->
                    oauth2ResourceServer
                            .jwt(jwt ->
                                    jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(new MyAuthenticatonConverter())
                                            .decoder(createJWTDecoderX()))
            ));
    return http.build();
}


Is Spring Boot concerned for the JWT signing part? I don't think so because you say you're using Nimbusds for that. If what you are generating using Java 11 is a valid signed JWT, could you try putting it on jwt.io for validation?
N.B: to validate signature on jwt.io you need to paste the public part of the JWK you use to sign the JWT

when i'am pasting a working token to jwt.io, its also says to me, that the signature is invalid, then i additiionally pasting my public key:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIBIDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEF....
But i still get this error, i dont understandt, how this jwt.io works

jwt.io says Invalid Signature for your JWT until you paste a valid public key in SPKI, PKCS #1, X.509 Certificate, or JWK string format.

Just for debugging purposes, in your getJWSSigner() method you could use keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec); to have your public key and then put it apart and use it for validation on jwt.io.
Since you're using nimbusds you can also see here https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/jwk-conversion to convert between java security key and nimbus JWK which will provide you a public JWK version of the key (json representation) which can be easily used on jwt.io

The same behavior is in Spring Boot 3.2.4 and NimbusJwtDecoder.
The signature comparison fails:  sun.security.rsa.RSASignature#engineVerify, lines 221-225.
jwt.io validates the token.

@JJFraney how do your code looks like? and which version ov NimbusJwtDecoder are you using?
I have com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:9.24.4 -> 9.37.3 and my NimbusJwtDecoder is in the Lib: spring-security-oauth2-jose:6.1.8

@pochopsp i've added "getJWSSigner()" code of Decoder and i could decode this.
Then i've compared token, which i decoded in "getJWSSigner()" with the token in my Www-Autheticate Header, and both tokes are equal.
JwtAuthenticationProvider still says that: Signed JWT rejected: Invalid signature
Maybe i need to configure JwtAuthenticationProvider somehow?

@RomaKap I would first check if the JWT is correctly signed with the key you expect on jwt.io before doing further investigations

@pochopsp so far i understood you. First stept: on left side of jwt.io i paste my token
Second Step: on right side bottom i paste my public key, where is written "Public Key in SPKI etc" and then it shoulds showe me automaticaly "Valid Signature" without doing or clicking somewhere else?

@RomaKap exactly. When you do these steps in the bottom left of the page the sentence "Invalid Signature" will become "Valid Signature"

@pochopsp i dont really understand jwt.io, because when i am pasting token and public key from where is not working and where is working, i get everytime "invalid signature.", also tried with encoded public key with base64.
JwtAuthenticationProvider from spring-security-oauth2-resource-server:5.7.8 accepts token, which has been en- and decoded with my key-pair
JwtAuthenticationProvider from spring-security-oauth2-resource-server:6.1.6 does not accept token, which has beend en- and decoded with my key-pair.
And jwt.io says in both cases on my token and public-key, that signature is invalid.

@RomaKap:  nimbus-jose-jwt: 9.24.4, spring-security-oauth2-jose: 6.2.3

@RomaKap jwt.io works like this: you paste a JWT (base64 token in the form of header.body.signature) in the left side, in the bottom right side where is written "Public Key in SPKI ..." you paste your public key, common formats are X.509 PEM (the one that have -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- in the first line, base64 text lines in the middle and -----END PUBLIC KEY----- on the last line) or JWK (Json Web Key). If you want to test how jwt.io works, you can use a jwt generator online like this: https://dinochiesa.github.io/jwt/ to have some sample valid JWT and public keys

I've solved my issue. The problem was in my securityFilterChain, which i did not post here. I used "oauth2ResourceServer" in my chain two times for two different routes. When i've deleted one, the first one, which not worked before, starts working.

could you please add your SecurityFilterChain in the Question, and how you modified it in the answer?

please look on my edited post on bottom
